# Representing translation by matrix multiplication in higher dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

#### Problem

There is a translation (shift) by vector $t$. If we want to display this shift as a matrix multiplication by T, what are the dimensions of T (number of rows and columns)?

#### Progress

I think the answer is 2 columns by the multiplication and the same number of rows. I found this answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29)  but I am not sure this answer is right. Can someone tell me if the answer is right or help me with the right answer.

Comment: Are the vectors in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @naslundx i dont know. that is not described in the task.

Comment: What I mean is - how many coordinates are there? Is the vector $(1,2)$ for example or $(1,2,3)$? Or is that not stated either?

Comment: @naslundx that is not stated either. the whole question is this:  There is a translation (shift) instead of vector t. If we want to display this shift as a matrix multiplication by T what are the dimensions of T (number of rows and columns).

Comment: translations are not linear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you have found, in the example, they translate a vector with $3$ coordinates by using a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Let me try to explain it more clearly:

Let's say the vector $t = (t_1, \dots, t_n)$ has $n$ coordinates. We want to translate this vector by another vector $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, in other words calculate $t + x$.

We can represent this by a translation matrix $T$ so that $Tt = t + x$ in the following way:

1) Write $t$ as $(t_1, \dots, t_n, 1)$.

2) Create the matrix 
$$T = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & x_1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & x_2 \\ \vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & x_n \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Now $Tt = t + x$ (try to calculate this product yourself).

Thus we see that if $t$ has $n$ coordinates, then $T$ must have $n+1$ rows and columns.

Comment: I think i get it. Then the answer of my question is the original number of rows + 1 and the original number of columns + 1.

Comment: @user1679481 Note that a vector has only 1 column and n rows or n columns and 1 row. Either way you will need a matrix with n+1 rows and n+1 columns.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the answer!